# Extension of continuous function to boundary

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb R^n$.  Suppose the function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ can be extended to a continuous function from $Closure(U)$. Does that necessarily implies $f$ is uniformly continuous.

If the set $U$is bounded then then this holds. But for non bounded sets, I think it may not holds. For example $f=x^2$, for $x\in (0,\infty)=U$.

So what is the necessary condition for function to continously extend to its boundary

Comment: So "unifomly continouus on every bounded subset" seems necessary. (Note that on the other hand uniform continuity is certainly not sufficient)

Comment: A (somehow informative) necessary condition for extending continuous functions to the boudary/closure of an open set might be a bit tricky, but it is true that given $S$ a subset of a metric space and $f:S\to X$ with $X$ a complete metric space, then $f$ extends to a uniformly continuous function $\overline S\to X$ if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous on $S$.

Comment: @Gae. S. I Know if $f $ is uniformly continuous then it extends to a continuous function. (I don't know it is uniformly continuous). Is the proof easy or non trivial?

Comment: @LordShadow It's the same proof, you just need to add the observation that if, say, $\delta_\varepsilon$ works for $\varepsilon$ over $S$, then something like $\frac13\delta_{\varepsilon}$ works for $2\varepsilon$ over $\overline S$.

Comment: Got it @Gae.S. I haven't saw it before that's why I asked. Now I got it. Thanks